# Sample code for a slideshow in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for some sample code to reference of a slideshow built in android. I was looking at these and they seem perfect but they only offer the .apk to download. I want to be able to download and see all of the file so i can learn from them. Can anyone help me find similar code or be able to read these?

http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow/

http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow-widget/

Comment: Thank you both so much i cant believe i missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Google code link of your question: check the tab labelled 'Source' and use subversion to get code out the the repository.

Comment: How would i download all of the files from there instead of just viewing the code?

Answer (score 1):

Peter,

The source is provided: http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Alternatively, you can checkout a copy of the software using [subversion](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).  follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow/source/checkout

Comment: How would i download all of the files from there instead of just viewing the code?

Answer (score 0):

go to checkout tag, path is given over there , copy that path and run it in your linux terminal.it will download the code for you.